# Error: A value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'AbstractNode?' in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

When I launched my flutter app this error showed

```
Launching lib/main.dart on RMX1941 in debug mode...
: Error: A value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'AbstractNode?'.
- 'RenderObject' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('../../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart').
- 'AbstractNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart' ('../../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart').

    final AbstractNode? parentNode = parent;
                                     ^
: Error: The getter 'direction' isn't defined for the class 'AbstractNode?'.
- 'AbstractNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart' ('../../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart').

Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'direction'.
      return parentNode.direction;
                        ^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/k7/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy' line: 1297

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/home/k7/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Before this error I added some dependencies
[connection_notifier](https://pub.dev/packages/connection_notifier) and
[screen_protector](https://pub.dev/packages/screen_protector). Later I removed these dependencies and updated Dart Sdk and Flutter Sdk to the latest version. This error still Shows. Please help to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.